# Should I replace a constant with static methods, if that constant usually 'cooperate' with a specific operator?

Tags: coding-style, static-methods, operators, constants

For example, to convert between g and kg, I have a constant 1000:

```
public static final float G_TO_KG=1000;
.
.
.
this.result = someResult*1000;
```

I found G_TO_KG always bind to operator '*'. So my question is, is it better to define a static method:

```
public static float gToKg(result){
    return result*1000;
}
```

So that I would not use wrong operator, also don't need to repeat the operator each time?

Comment: You want to write an entire method to save one character?

Comment: So 1000 grams are one million kilograms in your world?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it's not about saving some typing, it's about eliminating a possible source of errors: Do I multiply or divide here? In fact, OP's example contains exactly one such error – with a function, it can be fixed in one place.

Comment: @amon: My question was rhetorical.  See the OP's edit, though I'm still not convinced of his revised reasoning.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean to define a transformation, you should definitely make a function rather than a number.

I would even say your original name is wrong, it should rather be `G_IN_KG`